# Need Clarification regarding Reputations

Tags: discussion, support

This is my All Time rank I checked at time **UTC 17:52**[image]
Reputations in this is **362**

When I went back to my profile, and there I saw my reputations are 360.[image]

Can anybody clarify me why is this so? A bug or something else?

Comment: a post that you edited got deleted most likely

Comment: Was your reputation ever 362?

Comment: No. Till now it is 360 only as I had seen.

Comment: Go to your user page. Click on the reputation tab and check the box that says "Show removed posts." Do you see anything that deducted two rep?

Comment: Yeah I got it. **-2 15 hours ago removed Chatbox with PHP doesn't work** But it must reflect everywhere on SO

Comment: The All Time rank page only gets refreshed once a day, at 00:00 UTC. That's why the reputation you see is different.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ (Presumably this wasn't the first comment because of caching, somehow.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I didn't get you. What are you trying to express?

Comment: @choxx: My meaning was stale because the cache was misconfigured. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As according to   **Carrie Kendall** and   **mmking** (replied in comments), the difference in reputations is because of the removed post I edited before and the reputations for ALL TIME are refreshed once a day, at 00:00 UTC. That's why there is a difference in reputations.

Thanks to both of you.